# html css toggle show/hide a div box when click like in facebook navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hi i wanted to make a similar dropdown div just like on facebook
here
the problem is the div doesnt stay when you hover out.how can i toggle it. like it will only disappear when you click outside the div? like facebook navigation bar?
[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/ic6bfl.png]

CSS

```
    .divs {
        display: none;
    }

    a:hover + .divs {
        display: block;
        background-color:white;
    }
```

HTML

```
    <a><img src="someIconsButtons.png"></a>
    <div class="divs">
    Stuff here...
    </div>
```

how can i attain that? thanks please be gentle guys im kinda newbie :))

Comment: i checked it on fiddle it's working: demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/XegE3/4/

Comment: That should work. Clarify your problem.

Comment: thanks but the problem is the div doesnt stay when you hover out.. how can i toggle it. like it will only disappear when you click outside the div? like facebook navigation bar?

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS

```
.divs 
{
  display: none;
}
a:hover + .divs 
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: purple;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.divs:after
{
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-bottom: 20px solid purple; 
   border-left: 10px solid transparent; 
   border-right: 10px solid transparent; 
   margin: -40px 50px 10px 10px;
}
```

**LIVE DEMO**

```css
.divs {
  display: none;
}

a:hover+.divs {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: purple;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.divs:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 20px solid purple;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  margin: -40px 50px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<a><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7eOO.jpg?s=32&g=1" /></a>
<div class="divs">
  Stuff here...
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but the problem is the div doesnt stay when you hover out.. how can i toggle it. like it will only disappear when you click outside the div? like facebook navigation bar?

Comment: @wemdy : like this http://jsfiddle.net/nvBYL/5/ ? add some jquery effects with this code. go through this following link to know about jquery effects http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/ & http://jqueryui.com/effect/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `jQuery`.
Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<a id="showdivblock">Show Div Block</a>
<div id="divblock">
here you go..
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#divblock 
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#divblock:after
{
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-bottom: 20px dashed blue; 
   border-left: 10px solid transparent; 
   border-right: 10px solid transparent; 
   margin: -40px 50px 10px 10px;
}
```

and here is a key what you want,

**jQuery:**

```
$('#divblock').hide();
$('#showdivblock').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#divblock').slideToggle();
});
$('#divblock').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function(){
     $('#divblock').slideUp();
});
```

**LIVE DEMO**

```js
$('#divblock').hide();
$('#showdivblock').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#divblock').slideToggle();
});
$('#divblock').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
  $('#divblock').slideUp();
});
```

```css
#divblock {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#divblock:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 20px dashed blue;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  margin: -40px 50px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="showdivblock">Show Div Block</a>
<div id="divblock">
  here you go..
</div>
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my jQuery solution,

I made your box of stuff display on hover and then if the body is clicked it is hidden.

```
$('img').hover(function(){
   $('div#box').show();
});
$('body').click(function(){
   $('div#box').hide();
});
```

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate. http://jsfiddle.net/joey6978/zLXK8/