# Making a toggle-able navigation bar with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar

Used the top answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693509/html-css-toggle-show-hide-a-div-box-when-click-like-in-facebook-navigation) to make a navigation bar that appears when you click on a logo image, and disappears when you click somewhere that's not on the logo image. It only partially works. Two main issues here:

1. The nav bar displays by default when the page is loaded. I want it to be hidden by default.
2. The nav bar disappears when I click outside of the div, but won't reappear.

HTML:

```
<img src="logo2.jpg" id="showdivblock" /> <!-- this is the logo that should toggle the nav bar -->
<div class="sidenav" id="divblock">
   <a href="about.php">About</a>
   <a href="collections.php">Collections</a>
   <a href="custom.php">Custom Orders</a>
   <a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#divblock {
   position: absolute;
}

#divblock:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width:0;
  height:0;
}
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('#divblock').hide();
$('#showdivblock').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#divblock').slideToggle();
});
$('#divblock').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function(){
     $('#divblock').slideUp();
});
```

which is linked to my HTML/CSS file using this code in the  tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="navbar.js"></script>
```

Comment: Clarification: the <script type="text/javascript" src="navbar.js"></script> is inside the head tags of the HTML file.

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/myko1xe2/2/

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the script being run immediately as it's loaded and before the dom is loaded. So there would be no `#divblock` or `#showdiv` elements in existence to receive the click event at that moment.

You can either use jQuery's document ready...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // place code referring to dom elements here
});
```

Or place your script at the bottom, just inside your `</body>` tag.

Or use jQuery's `on()` which puts the burden of delegation on an existing element...

```
$(document).on('click','#showdivblock',function(){
  // place code referring to dom elements here      
});
```

The reason your last line works (makes your block hide) is that `$(document)` does indeed exist at that moment and can get assigned a click event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to show and hide menu and click outside the div to hide menu .

```
/*Hide menu by default*/
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#divblock").hide();
});

$(document).on("click", function () {
  $("#divblock").slideToggle();
});

/*When menu button is clicked, toggle the menu*/
$("#showdivblock").click(function(event){
 event.stopPropagation();
 $("#divblock").slideToggle();
});
```